# Cross Browser issue with JavaScript Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, date, cross-browser

So I got my code to work just fine in Chrome. In FF I get the first two alerts with the dates and they're formatted properly and everything but if a past date is chosen it doesn't throw the third alert. In IE I get all three alerts but even if I choose a future date. As I mentioned Chrome works as it should so if anyone can provide some insight into making it work across them all that'd be great.

```
 function check()
{
   var selecteddate = document.form1.selectmonth.value + "-" + document.form1.selectday.value + "-" + document.form1.selectyear.value;
   var d = new Date();
   var today = (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear();

   // I'd then make some alerts and it'd return the selected date and today with no problem
   alert(selecteddate);
   alert(today)
   //Now for the if statement is where it just stops working. I think maybe I'm doing
   //something wrong just solely in the if statement.
     if(new Date(selecteddate) < new Date(today))
       {
       alert("Past dates are not valid");
       return false;
       }
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://grover.open2space.com/jquery.dates/home  ?

Comment: You may want to use the `new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])` constructor and not the one that relies on the string representation of the date. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @jeromeG That seems like a calendar control? I'm not wanting to use a calendar control for this project. Thank you for the link though, I may use it in future projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your dates are invalid to FF, use `"/"` in place of the `"-"` for `selecteddate` and `today`.

or what about just using

```
       if(selecteddate < today)
```

instead of

```
  if(new Date(selecteddate) < new Date(today))
```

Comment: That worked great. I had tried doing the first if statemet you provided earlier when working on this but still had the "-" for the date. I changed the dates to "/" and changed the if statement and it's working like a charm now. Thank you so much.